# Thread body not executed

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I written this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* cuoco(void* arg)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Inizio codice cuoco\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"Fine codice cuoco\n");
    return NULL;
}

void* cameriere(void* arg)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Inizio codice cameriere\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"Fine codice cameriere\n");
    return NULL;
}

void* cliente(void* arg)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Inizio codice cliente\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"Fine codice cliente\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void* (*routine)(void*);
    void* result;
    routine=cuoco;
    pthread_t thread_cuoco,thread_cameriere,thread_cliente;
    pthread_create(&thread_cuoco,NULL,routine,*argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Just to test how threads work.But the body of the function cuoco is never executed.This because it shall print "Inizio codice cuoco" and "fine codice cuoco" but it does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`pthread_join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html), so that your `main` function waits for the thread to execute before terminating the program.

```
pthread_create(&thread_cuoco,NULL,routine,*argv);

int res = pthread_join(thread_cuoco, NULL);
```

Comment: ..or some other means of preventing the exit of the main thread.  pthread_join is not the only choice and, in general, can be a bad one eg. when the work threads do not normally exit at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your primary thread returns from `main` which destroys the whole process and kills all the threads. Returning from `main` is similar to calling `exit`.

As an alternative to using `pthread_join`, what you can do is terminate your primary thread by a call to `pthread_exit`.   Calling `pthread_exit` will terminate just the primary thread.

A POSIX threaded application keeps running until all of its threads exit, or until the process is exited.

(If joinable threads are not collected with `pthread_join`, that can cause a resource leak, but it's not a problem in your program, or in general for threads that endure until the end of the application. Still, it's good "programming manners" to make every such thread that is not going to be joined a detached thread.)